# Couchbase properties file in classpath

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, couchbase

Im working with Java backend using Tomcat and trying to connect to a hosted instance of couchbase. I have setup up the path to my config directory in ../tomcat/Catalina/localhost/context.xml.default

```
<Parameter name="CONFIG_DIRECTORY" value="/opt/platform/conf" override="false"/>
```

Also I have set a CLASSPATH param in ../tomcat/bin/setenv.sh

```
CLASSPATH=/opt/platform/conf/
```

Below is the snippet of code I am working with :

```
    String initialNodes = RuntimeData.INSTANCE.getConfigurationValue("MYNODES");
    String bucketId = RuntimeData.INSTANCE.getConfigurationValue("MYBUCKET");
    System.out.println("Creating cluster for " + initialNodes);
    try {
        System.out.println("HOST INET ADDRESS : " + InetAddress.getByName(initialNodes));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("UNKNOWN HOST EXCEPTION : " + initialNodes);
    }

    cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(initialNodes.split(","));
    System.out.println("Creating bucket for " + bucketId);
    bucket = cluster.openBucket(bucketId, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Creating graph.");
    graph = new CBGraph();
```

In this code I have some debug logging and I can confirm that I do pull the correct values in for the initialNodes and the bucket. My issue currently comes in on the last line when I try to create a new CBGraph().

I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationException: No valid node found to bootstrap from. Please check your network configuration.
```

My guess is that somehow the properties file that contains all of the connection info for my couchbase server is either not getting loaded into the classpath ... or it is getting loaded later than I need it too.

The only verification I have been able to do that adding the CLASSPATH setting to setenv.sh is that once tomcat is running I do see the path in classpath if I do ps auxw|grep tomcat.

Any help with this issue is welcome. I have looked at some other posts but im not sure exactly the issue im trying to solve here other than the error I get.

ADDITION:

Looking at the INFO logs at runtime I can verify that the dir containing my couchbase .properties file IS in the classpath. BUT ... it looks like couchbase is trying to initialize using default values (copied below)

```
INFO: Using the following configuration ...
Oct 24, 2016 3:08:09 PM com.couchbase.graph.conn.ConnectionFactory      createCon
INFO: hosts = ubuntu-local
```

Answer (score 0):

The adresses you are specifying might not be valid hostnames (or ip addresses), and you should also see one of these INFO log messages:

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-jvm-core/blob/4127377b8bd057ed291176d568a1e868796e4e5a/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/core/message/cluster/SeedNodesRequest.java#L85-L102

Comment: Should I be calling SeedNodesRequest? I thought I was ok just doing :   cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(initialNodes.split(","));  with my list of initial nodes.

Comment: Yes it is okay to do it like you has shown, but could you show what initialNodes  look like? They should be either DNS names or IP addresses

Comment: The initial nodes are just DNS names for the AWS nodes. Im loading in one only ... i guess I could load in more. As far as proper formatting goes if I have a node named in my cluster :    aws4-74-22-973-9.uk-east-9.compute.amazonaws   (this is not real by the way)  is the proper formatting as far as loading initial nodes just that host name or do i need "http" in front of it ... or ".com" on the end etc ?

Comment: The address string should be resolvable by InetAddress.getByName(node). Could you craft simple app and just try to resolve one of your hosts? http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String). Any INFO log output btw about your hosts? Like "Unknown host yourhost.amazonaws in bootstrap list"?

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. The good news is that I added some logging and I AM able to resolve an inet address for my host. So it does look like I am at least able to get to the node and resolve an address.

Comment: I am still getting the same error when i create a Graph Object though. Im still concerned that even though I have a connection to the Couchbase Cluster I may not be getting to the actual nodes etc. In short Im worried that my properties file is not loading into the class path correctly.

Comment: Try to curl this URL for some of the nodes: http://{HOSTNAME}:8091/pools/default. There will be "nodes" array and each node has "hostname", could you check that those hostnames are also reachable from the client machine? For example with jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) the command will be "curl -s http://localhost:8091/pools/default | jq .nodes[].hostname"

Comment: When I curl. I get the array of nodes. I see all of the hostnames. I do see the specific hostname that my program is trying to access. I am able to curl it from the client machine. And im assuming that it is reachable from within my app as I am able to resolve the ip address.

Comment: Does the Java API InetAddress.getByName() also resolves it? Just to clarify: do you see this message being logged? https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-jvm-core/blob/4127377b8bd057ed291176d568a1e868796e4e5a/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/core/message/cluster/SeedNodesRequest.java#L95

Comment: Please note the updated code in the original post. I added the try/catch to look at the host ip address as i run through. Currently this is the log output I see. 

Creating cluster for MYNODE
HOST INET ADDRESS : MYNODE/MYHOSTIP
Creating bucket for Dev_Users
Creating graph.

Exception in thread "FileLogWriter" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Blah 
Blah
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationException: No valid node found to bootstrap from. Please check your network configuration.

The caused by error points specifically back to 

graph = new CBGraph();

Comment: Looking at the logs closer I have updated the ticket with some INFO logs. It for sure looks like couchbase is trying to initialize the graph object using default cluster values instead of my properties file.  I can see the correct  dir in the classpath at runtime but couchbase clearly is not using it .